# Insert rows to dataset depending on time difference between rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How would I go about inserting Rows into an already existing dataset.
The shown table is a dumbed down verion of my data which I have available as Dataset.

I want to insert a new row whenever the time difference between two consecutive rows jumps over the next full hour. All columns except for the new time should be the same as the row above.

Either datetime or date & time is sufficient. I just put them in my example to show that I have access to all of them.

My general idea would be to calculate the amount of hour skips between two rows, create a new dataset, join it with the original one, and sort it.

```
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|  status|           datetime|      date|    time|
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|   start|2017-01-01 07:15:12|2017-01-01|07:15:12|
|    init|2017-01-01 07:22:12|2017-01-01|07:22:12|
|A_status|2017-01-01 07:31:12|2017-01-01|07:31:12|
|B_status|2017-01-01 10:30:12|2017-01-01|10:30:12|
|C_Status|2017-01-01 11:15:12|2017-01-01|11:15:12|
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+

+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|  status|           datetime|      date|    time|
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|   start|2017-01-01 07:15:12|2017-01-01|07:15:12|
|    init|2017-01-01 07:22:12|2017-01-01|07:22:12|
|A_status|2017-01-01 07:31:12|2017-01-01|07:31:12|
|A_status|2017-01-01 08:00:00|2017-01-01|08:00:00|
|A_status|2017-01-01 09:00:00|2017-01-01|09:00:00|
|A_status|2017-01-01 10:00:00|2017-01-01|10:00:00|
|B_status|2017-01-01 10:30:12|2017-01-01|10:30:12|
|B_status|2017-01-01 11:00:00|2017-01-01|11:00:00|
|C_Status|2017-01-01 11:15:12|2017-01-01|11:15:12|
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

My first thought was calculating the timedifference in hours and if it is >= 1 generate that amount of rows in a new dataset and join it to the original.
The problem is that it doesn't detect the skip from B_status to C_status since it is only 3/4 hours.

```
val df9 = df3.withColumn("time_diff", ((unix_timestamp(lead($"datetime", 1).over(Window.orderBy("datetime"))) - unix_timestamp($"datetime"))/60/60)).show
```

My next thought would be extracting the hour part of the time field and subtracting those. This will result int he correct amount of lines though the jump from HH24 to HH00 would need to be handled extra.

I also read about the explode function since this could generate new rows with the same data though I have no idea yet if this function is applicable in this case.

Does someone have any hints or implementations to help me out? Maybe there is an easier way to achieve this. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: You could join with a dataset that has all the exact hours, then fill the missing values for these time values with the Spark window API

Comment: @Fabich This seems like a really smart idea. I just need to get the min and max value for datetime and create a template to join with my data. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by using `explode` function but for that you need complex combination of `hour, lead, Window, udf, unix_timestamp, select, SimpleDateFormat` and many more functions which are explained below.

Given the `dataframe` as

```
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|status  |datetime           |date      |time    |
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|start   |2017-01-01 07:15:12|2017-01-01|07:15:12|
|init    |2017-01-01 07:22:12|2017-01-01|07:22:12|
|A_status|2017-01-01 07:31:12|2017-01-01|07:31:12|
|B_status|2017-01-01 10:30:12|2017-01-01|10:30:12|
|C_Status|2017-01-01 11:15:12|2017-01-01|11:15:12|
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

Only `status` and `datetime` columns are important as `date` and `time` columna can be derived from `datetime` column which is to be changed. So you have to select only two and get the hour difference with the previous row as

```
val df2 = df.select($"status", unix_timestamp($"datetime").cast(TimestampType).as("datetime"), (hour(lead($"datetime", 1).over(Window.orderBy("datetime"))) - hour($"datetime")).as("hour"))
```

which should give you

```
+--------+---------------------+----+
|status  |datetime             |hour|
+--------+---------------------+----+
|start   |2017-01-01 07:15:12.0|0   |
|init    |2017-01-01 07:22:12.0|0   |
|A_status|2017-01-01 07:31:12.0|3   |
|B_status|2017-01-01 10:30:12.0|1   |
|C_Status|2017-01-01 11:15:12.0|null|
+--------+---------------------+----+
```

Now that you have the hour difference, you can get the *array of datetime* from the `datetime` value to the *hour difference datetime* which can be done by defining a `udf` function as

```
def getDiffDateArray = udf((date : String, hour: Int, value : Int) => {
  if((value - 1) > 0) {
    var array = Array.empty[String]
    for(time <- 0 to value){
      val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      val originalDate = format.parse(date)
      val calendar = Calendar.getInstance
      calendar.setTimeInMillis(originalDate.getTime)
      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour+time)
      if(time != 0){
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
      }
      array = array ++ Array(format.format(calendar.getTime))
    }
    array}
  else Array(date)
})
```

You can use the `explode` function on the *array of datetime* and get the `date` and `time` columns by doing the following

```
def getTimeFromeDateTime = udf((date: String) =>{
  val parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  val timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
  val time = parseFormat.parse(date)
  timeFormat.format(time)
})

df2.withColumn("datetime", explode(getDiffDateArray($"datetime", hour($"datetime"), when($"hour".isNotNull, $"hour").otherwise(lit(0)))))
    .drop("hour")
    .withColumn("date", $"datetime".cast(DateType))
    .withColumn("time", getTimeFromeDateTime($"datetime"))
    .show(false)
```

This should give you your desired result as

```
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|status  |datetime           |date      |time    |
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
|start   |2017-01-01 07:15:12|2017-01-01|07:15:12|
|init    |2017-01-01 07:22:12|2017-01-01|07:22:12|
|A_status|2017-01-01 07:31:12|2017-01-01|07:31:12|
|A_status|2017-01-01 08:00:00|2017-01-01|08:00:00|
|A_status|2017-01-01 09:00:00|2017-01-01|09:00:00|
|A_status|2017-01-01 10:00:00|2017-01-01|10:00:00|
|B_status|2017-01-01 10:30:12|2017-01-01|10:30:12|
|C_Status|2017-01-01 11:15:12|2017-01-01|11:15:12|
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is working. The only thing I had to change in order to get the desired output is the if clause in your getDiffDateArray to `if(value > 0)`

Comment: It works for my provided input. Though when there is a gap between the days f.e. we jump from januaray first to january 3rd the code does not work anymore. I will have to make some adjustements

Comment: I think I got it to work correctly now. I added a day column with `val ds2 = ds.withColumn("day", dayofyear(lead($"datetime", 1).over(Window.orderBy("datetime"))) - dayofyear($"datetime"))`

Then I calculated the correct amount of hours with this udf: `def getHours = udf((day: Int, hour: Int) => {
      if(hour >= 0){day*24+hour}
      else{day*24+hour}
    })`

Comment: great feeling to have helped you find your own ways. :) thanks for the acceptance and upvote :)

Comment: Do you know if there a way to specifiy which columns should be copied when using explode? I have to calculate the sum over a column and now the numbers don't add up since I am adding copies of it.

Comment: @user2811630, I didn't understand your question. explode function will generate the array column into separate rows but the other columns get duplicated. if you want to sum certain columns but without duplicates, then you should sum before applying explode.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to exclude specific columns from this duplication process

Comment: what do you mean by specific columns? can you give an example?

Comment: In your previous comment you stated that "but the other columns get duplicated" . I want some of them not to get duplicated but filled with a default value like null or 0 or ""

Comment: @user2811630 you can use `select`  for selecting the columns you want duplicate and for the columns you don't want duplicates you can use `join`. I hope its clear :)